# Ball only bounces back and forth in a diagonal line?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, background="green")
canvas.pack()

speed_x = 5
speed_y = 5

ball = canvas.create_oval(0,0,32,32,fill="blue")

while True:
    canvas.move(ball, speed_x, speed_y)
    canvas.after(30)
    canvas.update()

    coords = canvas.coords(ball)

    if coords[2] >= 500:
        speed_x = -5
    if coords[0] <= 0:
        speed_x = 5
    if coords[3] >= 500:
        speed_y = -5
    if coords[1] <= 0:
        speed_y = 5
```

My goal is to have the ball bounce around the screen forever. I got it to bounce off the walls, but only from one corner to another. It just bounces back and forth from (0,0) and (500,500).
I don't see where I went wrong. How do I make it bounce in random directions? I tried changing the starting point but that didn't do anything.

I was thinking I made a mistake in lines 18 and below, but I used <= and >= so shouldn't that apply to all of the numbers above 0 and below 500? Why doesn't it move to other places?

Comment: You have the right idea, and your code works correctly. Just think about the direction of the ball, what would you expect it to happen when it hit a corner?. Now try changing your area from a square of 500x500, to a rectangle of 400x500 and see what happens. Hope this puts you in the right direction

Comment: It definitely helped, thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> It just bounces back and forth from (0,0) and (500,500)

This is normal, when encountering an angle of wall (like (0,0) and (500,500)), it bounce two times, resulting in reversing the direction (180°) instead of 90° bounce.

Set your ball to another initial position:

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, background="green")
canvas.pack()

speed_x = 5
speed_y = 5

ball = canvas.create_oval(0,0,32,32,fill="blue")
canvas.move(ball, 100, 0) # move ball away from diagonal.

while True:
    canvas.move(ball, speed_x, speed_y)
    canvas.after(30)
    canvas.update()

    coords = canvas.coords(ball)

    if coords[2] >= 500:
        speed_x = -5
    if coords[0] <= 0:
        speed_x = 5
    if coords[3] >= 500:
        speed_y = -5
    if coords[1] <= 0:
        speed_y = 5
```

> How do I make it bounce in random directions?

When encountering a wall, set `speed_x` and `speed_y` to random values.

Edit: Running the code and setting the ball to a position not in the diagonal make it work like expected.

Comment: Changing the speed_x and speed_y to random values worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you start at (0,0) and move up and right at constant speed, then you will reach (500, 500), where the ball will hit the top right corner of the screen. At that point both the x speed and y speed will change to negative because of:

```
   if coords[2] >= 500:
        speed_x = -5
    if coords[3] >= 500:
        speed_y = -5
```

Which means that the ball will move left and down. So the problem is that you hit the top right corner exactly, reversing both the horizontal and vertical speed simultaneously.

If you start at a different position (say (0, 50)), then you will hit the point (450, 500), at which point the x speed will be reversed, and the y speed will continue to be positive. That should hopefully fix it! Alternatively, change the size of the canvas to something that isn't square.